# Number of solution for $x^a \equiv b$ mod p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the integer equation $x^a \equiv b$ mod $p$. How can I find all integers mod $p$ that solve this equation? Below I leave my work so far:

I know that for $d|p-1$ there are $d$ elements $\{q_1, \ldots q_d \} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ st. their order divides d,
ie. $q_i^d \equiv 1$ mod $p$ $\forall i$.

Let $d = \text{hfc}(a, p-1)$. If $x_0$ is a solution for $x^a \equiv b$ mod $p$ then so will $x_0 q_i$ $\forall i$. 
So we have at least $d$ solutions. If $y$ is a solution, then $x_0^a \equiv y^a \equiv b$ mod $p$. So $(y^{-1}x_0)^a \equiv 1$ mod $p$. So $y$ is of the form $x_0 q_i$.

Hence if there is one solution there are exactly hcf$(a, p-1)$ solutions.

The only question that remains open for me now is whether there exists such a solution, as for example $x^2 \equiv 4$ mod $5$ has no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x^a\equiv y^a$, then $(x^{-1}y)^a\equiv 1\bmod p$.

We conclude $y\equiv xw$ where $w$ is an element such that $w^a\equiv 1 \bmod p$

We know that primitive roots $\bmod p$ exist, and it is such easy to prove that the possible values of $w$ are those of the form $r^{k((p-1)/gcd(p-1,a))}$, where $r$ is any primitive root.

So your idea is correct !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now see that the existence of one such solution implies that there are exactly hcf $(a, p-1)$ solutions. However, I do not see how the existence of a primitive root implies that there is a solution. For example, I know that $x^2 \equiv 2$ mod $5$ has no solution.

Comment: The map that sends $x$ to $x^{a}$ has fibers of size $gcd(p-1,a)$ and therefore has an image of size $(p-1)/gcd(p-1,a)$. So yes, some of those equations don't have solutions. I hope this helps.